# Panel Could not set Visible True in MDI

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I am using C#. Net Windows application.

I have one MDI parent form and many child forms. I put panel in MDI parent form and drag several button inside panel.

When I click the button they open another child form and set visible false to panel
like this (sample code):

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    panel1.Visible = false;

    ChildForm Form2 = new ChildForm();
    Form2.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;           
    Form2.Show();
}
```

Now they perfectly working. What the problem is, when I close the child form the panel could not visible in MDI parent form. Its always panel visible false. I set to true., see my code.

```
private void ChildForm _FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
{
     this.Dispose();
     MDI md = new MDI();
     md.panel1.Visible = true;
}
```

am also using `BringToFront`, `SendToBack`. No use. Please assist.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

hi friends i Solved this and i got worked now...
here the Solution..

```
>  private void ChildForm_FormClosed(object sender,FormClosedEventArgs e)
>         {
>             MDI md = (MDI)this.MdiParent;
>             md.panel1.Visible = true;
>         }
```

Answer (score 1):

The problems are:

- you create a new instance of *MDI form* in your *child form* with `MDI md = new MDI();`

  You should instead retrieve the instance of the opened *MDI* and set `md.panel1.Visible =
  true;` on this instance. You can use the `MdiParent` property.

  ```
  MDI md = (MDI)this.MdiParent;
  md.panel1.Visible = true;
  ```
- and you call `This.Dispose` before your the code that set panel visible. I am not sure that the code which is after `This.Dispose` will be executed...